# how do i set ubuntu to recognize my hardware

Tags: 14.04

i have a thumb drive and hard drive that Ubuntu recognizes as being 1/16 of the capacity short when installed and then takes 1/8 of the space to index.

Answer (score 0):

Hard-drives and Flash-drives always have less capacity when formatted depending on the filesystem used and the ares used to store file information...  Check this link for a better explanation: http://petapixel.com/2012/10/10/why-hard-drives-and-memory-cards-have-less-space-than-advertised/